# "android.permission.CAMERA" giving error on including in AndroidManifes.xml file

Tags: android, android-camera

this is my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.mycamera"> 
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and this is the corresponding **java file** for the above code:

```
package com.example.mycamera;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn;
ImageView imagedisplay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.image);
  imagedisplay = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_capture);

  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

          Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
          startActivityForResult(intent , 0);
      }
  });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode , int resultCode, Intent data){
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

       Bitmap bitmap= (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");           
       imagedisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

}

this is working fine without even including:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

in **AndroidManifest.xml file.**

**But on including the camera permission it is not working and showing the error your app has stopped working.**

Comment: please add stacktrace

Comment: "this is working fine without even including" -- then remove it, or use `requestPermissions()` to request it at runtime.

Comment: You are not getting runtime permission So you have add run time permission on Activity befor launch camera. It will work for you

Comment: include runtime [permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Comment: hello,@CommonsWare actually i am new to android so honestly i didnt't get this .Can u explain it with code and why does this happen ?

Comment: Try this at once     <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"
        android:required="true" />

Comment: You do not need the `CAMERA` permission to take a picture via `Intent`. However, if you list the `CAMERA` permission in your manifest, and attempt to do so without having that permission granted, it will throw a `SecurityException`. This was done to prevent confusion for end users who try to manually disable that permission in an app's Settings. Just remove the `CAMERA` permission from your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 
private ImageView imageView;
private static final int MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE = 100;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE);
            }
            else
            {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            } 
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE)
    {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {  
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {  
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }  
    } 
}
```

Comment: Use have to check for runtime permission for camera above api level 6

Comment: on running this :                                                                                                           protected void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
 showing error i.e illegal start of expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try once this :

```
private boolean isVersionBelowMarshmallow = false;

public boolean checkPermissionForCamera() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        isVersionBelowMarshmallow = true;
    }
    if (isVersionBelowMarshmallow)
        return true;
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these Solution Once :

```
if (checkAndRequestPermissions(getContext())) {

    }  

private boolean checkAndRequestPermissions(Context context) {

    int ExtstorePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int cameraPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    if (cameraPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    }
    if (ExtstorePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FlagUp Requires Access to Your Storage.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      //  finish();
        //super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FlagUp Requires Access to Camara.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       // finish();
    }
}
```